# Node-Red HTTP request node throws 1020 error on file download

Tags: node-red

I am trying to download a large JSON file via node-red and it throws an "error 1020". When I say "parse JSON" in the HTTP node, it will say parser error. However, parsing the array that is being downloaded works fine with Python or Java. When I download as UTF-8 string I get the error 1020.

This is the flow:

```
[{"id":"e0e091b8.2b78a","type":"http request","z":"95f2458b.b4a148","name":"Downloader","method":"GET","ret":"txt","paytoqs":false,"url":"https://JSONURLHERE","tls":"","persist":false,"proxy":"","authType":"","x":450,"y":300,"wires":[["53175134.cd5c9"]]},{"id":"1b838110.b3d76f","type":"inject","z":"95f2458b.b4a148","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":160,"y":380,"wires":[["c4816b73.f2bfe8"]]},{"id":"c4816b73.f2bfe8","type":"function","z":"95f2458b.b4a148","name":"","func":"msg.headers = {};\nmsg.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":240,"y":280,"wires":[["e0e091b8.2b78a"]]},{"id":"53175134.cd5c9","type":"debug","z":"95f2458b.b4a148","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":640,"y":320,"wires":[]}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't really help here without a sample of the downloaded data or the URL so we can try and download it ourselves. Also when you say large, just how big is it?

Comment: It's not 100% but are you saying you get the same error, regardless of the output type JSON or UTF-8? Also is there anything printed to the Node-RED log (not the debug sidebar) when the error occurs?

Comment: I now added a User-Agent and it works. msg.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36';